Why is this returning two orders of values? Why are the keys also in random and different orders?
This image contains all the details needed to understand this q
s = 'paper'
t = 'title'

And a simple dic storing char counts fails to return the values and keys in the same order. Why?
I expected them to return the same order of values (based on when they were added to the respective dicts).

Please type in code instead of images.

Edit your question and add your code as text, and please let us know which version of Python you are using to run the program.

Starting from Python 3.7, the standard dict maintains the order of items based on the insertion order. If your version is less than 3.7 you can use OrderedDict from collections to get expected result.
